# Write text with echo() after reloading page with header()

Tags: php, if-statement, header, echo

I have page called `account_settings.php` and it's consist of change password, change profile pic, change user details (name, bio etc.). My question is how to write message with `echo()` after redirecting page with `header()`.

Something like this:

```
if (true) 
{
    Do_Some_MySQL();
    header("Location: account_settings.php");
    echo "Success!";
}
else
{
    echo "Error!";
}
```

Thank you for all replies. ;-)

Comment: This is not possible if you redirect you redirected!

Comment: What you want to display header ?

Comment: If you use a `Location` header to redirect to another page, then you cannot produce any further output from the original page. One option would be to use a JavaScript redirect method.

Comment: You can't. `header()` used along with `Location:` redirects you to another page, so you cannot have something displayed after it. _The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set._  [source : php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: And it's not gonna work if I save success and error strings into session either?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't actually do something after sending a `Location` header - it is impossible.

Instead, you could use `$_SESSION` array value to perform your task. Like:

```
if (true) 
{
  Do_Some_MySQL();
  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Error!';
  header("Location: account_settings.php");
}

else
{
  echo "Error!";
}
```

And then on your account_setting.php:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['message'] ?>
```

This would be nice if the `account_settings.php` is not the same page as you currently are. Otherwise, you could use the following code:

```
if (true) 
{
  Do_Some_MySQL();
  $error = 'Success!';
  header("Location: account_settings.php");
}

else
{
  $error = "Error!";
}
```

And on the same page:

```
<?php if($error) echo $error; ?>
```

Also don't forget to include `session_start()` on both pages if you didn't it yet.

Comment: This solution seems to be good, but when I leave this page and get back the success or error text are still there.

Comment: Then try to flush a success/error message variables once you have loaded the page. Or just make them `$message = NULL`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a SESSION variable:
on redirect-page:

```
<?php
@session_start();

if(true){
   $_SESSION['success'] = 1;
   header("Location: account-settings.php");
}
?>
```

and on account-settings.php:

```
<?php
@session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['success'])){
   echo "Success!";
   unset($_SESSION['success']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot echo anything after you just redirected. The browser is already processing the request to redirect to another page, so it doesn't bother about displaying the message anymore. What you seem to be looking for is something called flash message. You can set a temporary message in the session and have it display on the new page. For example, in your `account_settings.php` page:

```
// Make sure you have an actual session
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

if (true) {
    Do_Some_MySQL();
    $_SESSION['flashMessage'] = 'Success!';
    header('Location: account_settings.php');
}
```

Then in your template file for account_settings, check if there is any flash message and display it accordingly (and unset it to avoid a loop):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['flashMessage'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['flashMessage'];
    unset($_SESSION['flashMessage']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These people are correct...you can't send headers after a redirect. Although I think this would be a beneficial alternative. To send a GET request in your header and process it on the receiving page. They are suggesting to use $_SESSION vars, but you can use GET vars. Ex:

```
    if (true) 
{
    //Do_Some_MySQL();
    header("Location: account_settings.php?message=success");
    //above has GET var message = Success
}
else
{
    header("Location: account_settings.php?message=error");
}
```

On your account_settings.php page have this code:

```
if (isset($_GET['message'])) {
    $message = $_GET['message'];
    if ($message == "success") {
         echo "Success";
    } else {
         echo "Error";
    }
}
```

This removes the need of CONSTANT SESSION vars. and gives you plenty of flexibility.

```
header("Location: account_settings.php?message=No%20results%20found");
//%20 are URL spaces. I don't know if these are necessary.
```

If you need you can add more then one.

```
header("Location: account_settings.php?message=error&reason=No%20Results&timestamp=" . Date());
```

then account_settings.php can be:

```
if (isset($_GET['message'])) {
    $message = $_GET['message'];
    $reason = $_GET['reason'];
    $time = $_GET['timestamp'];
    if ($message == "success") {
         echo "Success";
    } else {
         echo "Error: <br/>";
         echo "Reason: $reason";
    }
}
```

But remember GET exposes your messages in the browsers URL. So DON'T send sensitive information unless you secure it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the refresh time to zero it will work fine

```
echo $theMsg;
header("refresh:0;url=$url");
exit();
```